# Can't acces to php login with pdo and json

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

i have some problems with my login, in login.php is my form and my script

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Mensaje -->
    <div id="mensaje"></div>
    <form id="login-form" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Usuario" class="control-label col-xs-2">Usuario</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input id="Usuario" value="<?php echo $txtUsuario; ?>" name="Usuario" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Contrasena" class="control-label col-xs-2" >Contraseña</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input id="Contrasena" value="<?php echo $txtContrasena; ?>" name="Contrasena" type="password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Contraseña">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Sesion</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
        var objUsuario = new Object();
        objUsuario.Usuario =$('input#Usuario').val();
        objUsuario.Contrasena=$('input#Contrasena').val();

        var DatosJson = JSON.stringify(objUsuario);
        // Checking for blank fields.
        if( objUsuario.Usuario =='' || objUsuario.Contrasena ==''){
            $("#mensaje").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>HOLA HOLA HOLA: " +  "</div>");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border","2px solid red");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow","0 0 3px red");
            alert("Rellenar Campos");

        }else {
            $.post("LoginValidar.php",{ UsuarioPost: DatosJson},

        function(data, textStatus) {
            if(data.Estatus=='True') {

            $("#mensaje").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Mensaje: " + data.Msg + "</div>");
            $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
            $('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
            alert(data);

            } if(data.Estatus=='False'){
                $("form")[0].reset();
                $("#mensaje").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Mensaje: " + data.Msg + "</div>");
                $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
            alert(data);
            } else{
            alert(data);
                }   
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

and my file LoginValidar.php send the parameters to crud.php where is my PDO query

```
try
    {
        //$array    = array("Usuario"=>$Usuario, "Contrasena"=>$Contrasena);            
        include("constantes.php");
        $Usuario = $_POST["UsuarioPost"]; 
        $options  = array('uri' => URL_BASE,'location' => WEBSERVICE);
        $client   = new SoapClient(NULL, $options); 
        $response = $client->IniciarSesion($Usuario);
        echo $response;

        }catch(Exception  $e){
            echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
        }
```

> crud.php, i think the problem is in my crud because the parameters 
>   are sent but i cant login

```
public function IniciarSesion($CadenaJson){

    $ObjetoJson = json_decode($CadenaJson);
    $response   = array("Msg"=>"","Estatus"=>""); 

    try
    { 
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT usuario from USUARIOS WHERE usuario= :Usuario AND contrasena= :Contrasena");

        $stmt->bindparam(":Usuario",$ObjetoJson->Usuario);
        $stmt->bindparam(":Contrasena",$ObjetoJson->Contrasena);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if($rows > 0) {
            $response["Msg"] = "Login correct";
            $response["Estatus"] = "True"; 
        }
        else{
            echo "else";
        }



    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $response["Msg"]     = $e->getMessage();
        $response["Estatus"] = "False"; 
    }
    return json_encode($response);

}
```

> If i delete the **if** sentence i always receive true msg. With **if** i receive  this msg:   **"Msg":"","Estatus":""**
>   Thanks ... I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: I don't know if it is related to your problem, but `$rows` will be an array or `false` so comparing it to `0` does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks, i've changed it for rowCount..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to check the affected rows. You can do this by using `$stmt->rowCount()`

### Example

```
$stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){ //If at least 1 row is selected
            $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            //Do sth. here with your result if you want
            $response["Msg"] = "Login correct";
            $response["Estatus"] = "True"; 
        } else {
            echo "else";
        }
```

Comment: i've changed the code  and the rowCount result is always 0, I've realized that the username and password values have not been received. 
Now i'm going to check why the values aren't sent..